# Hashkey(MD5) generation for JSON data (ntext)column SQL server

Tags: sql-server, md5

We have to generate a hashkey column in a table for incremental load, where it has multiple JSON data (Ntext)columns with more than 40,000 characters and it varies.

Currently we are converting it to `varchar` and generating, but `varchar` has  limitation. Could you please suggest?

Comment: `varchar(max)` ?

Comment: Also, it might be better to write the MD5 sum with the record, i.e. generate it in the application, not in a separate step. In a wider sense it's not really useful to generate checksums over JSON, since there is more than one JSON representation of the same data.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)